# I decomposed only the first four components from PCA/EOF. Can I get the percent variance of each component against the entire dataset?

Tags: pca, eigenvalues

I am using NIPALS (non-linear iterative partial least squares) to get the loadings and scores from a PCA analysis. The reason I am using NIPALS rather than singular value decomposition is because NIPALS can accommodate missing data. Since, my data is very large 50000 by 300 it takes a lot of time to compute each the loadings and the scores from NIPALS.

I have computed the first four component of the PCA analysis. I am wondering if there is a way to compute the residual variance for the 5th to the 300th, without having to compute the eigenvalues of each component. Or if there are any other way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some digging and this might be possible!

1. Compute eigenvalues until you hit the "elbow" of the [Scree plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scree_plot#:%7E:text=The%20scree%20plot%20is%20used,known%20as%20a%20scree%20test.).

   - This can be subjective, so you can utilize an eigenvalue ratio test like the one proposed by [Ahn and Horenstein (2006)](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=1bf5a6ffb4f1bdaf4d6492f4a6ae88d59d624d2f).
   - This will compute ratios between consecutive eigenvalues, until you hit a spike (see figures below).
2. This test will give you a reasonable number of factors $r$ that are significant. As part of this process, you will compute $\lambda_{r+1}$.
3. Compute explained variance as about, since after the dip, the eigenvalues will be sufficiently small and about the same scale:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i}{\sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i + (N-r)\lambda_{r+1}}$$

$\underline{\textrm{Note}}$: This will provide a conservative **lower bound** for the explained variance. Because we know the eigenvalues are non-increasing, the true explained variance will only be higher!

Here are a few visuals of the method (taken from the 2006 paper above):

[image]
[image]